# How well does a Samsung qx411 (sandy bridge/optimus?) work with Ubuntu?

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, samsung

New to the site, and debating returning to Ubuntu. My question is tho, how will Ubuntu run on my laptop. It's a Samsung qx411, specs are:

**Processor:**

- Intel Core i5-2410M
- Processor Cores: 2
- Processor Speed: 2.3 GHz
- Processor Cache: 3 MB L3

**Storage & Memory:**

- Hard Drive Capacity: 640 GB
- RAM Size: 4 GB
- RAM Type: DDR3 SDRAM

**Graphics:**

- NVIDIA Optimus GeForce GT525
- Video Memory Configuration: Dedicated
- Dedicated Video Memory Size: 1 GB
- Wireless Display (WiDi) Capable: Yes

I would use the laptop for taking notes in school, power points, facebook, and last but not least, im an avid fan of Civ V. Reading the forums, i figure you can get CIV and steam to run through wine ok. However, i am really worried about Sandy Bridge and optimus support.

Has anyone with a laptop managed to get full sandy bridge support, and is there a way to get my nvidia graphics drivers working properly (ie i can use both the integrated and dedicated as please?)

Comment: 12.10 doesn't work well with my qx411, even jumped over to mint 14, same issue. I did replace my HDD with a solid state drive, not sure if that's the issue. 12.04 and mint 13 work great.

Answer (score 4):

I'm running qx411 while writing this, and ever thing is working great.

Some Quick Notes:

- Wifi good
- Mouse pad Better++   
  The mouse pad set up personally is way better in **Ubuntu** then **Windows**.  In **Windows** you are required to move your finger to the left side of the mouse pad to left click, and the right side of the mouse pad to right click.  Then you have to use this glitchy 2 finger scroll in windows that is annoying and jumpy.

   In **Ubuntu** click with one finger is single click, and click with two is right click.  The scroll is situated conveniently to the right, out of the way but still accessible.
- Sound good
- Graphics 
  The graphics work fine.  There are a couple options for drivers, but the default are working fine.

Just get a live cd or usb and test everything out.

It won't mess with your Operating System, unless you run the install.

### [Download & Install](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download)